# Java Constructor by String parameters

Tags: java, string, list, constructor

Hello my problem is that

```
DepositoBancario(String s){
         String[]v = s.split("[ :]");
         Integer n= v.length;
         if(n!=2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error"+s);
         banco= new String(v[0]);
         interes= new List(v[1]);
}
```

This constructor is for be able to build and object by a file and I want transform the element v[1] in List(interes).

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: can you show what is contain in banco and interes.

Comment: please provide some more information and we will try to help

Comment: private String banco;
private List<Integer> interes;

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need to create a String with `new String("")` you can just set `banco = v[0]`
2. List is an Interface and can not be instantiated via a constructor. What you need is a ArrayList for example. But this class doesn't have a Constructor for a Strign neither. What is in that String `v[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have one or more elements `(interes)` and you wants to convert them into list of elements. You can use something like this.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DepositoBancario {
    String banco;
    List<String> interes;

    public DepositoBancario(String s){
             String[]v = s.split("[ :]");
             Integer n= v.length;
             if(n!=2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error"+s);
             banco= v[0];
             if(v[1] != null){
                 interes = new ArrayList<String>();
             }
             for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
                 interes.add(v[i]);
    }
}
```

**Note** : Please consider the suggestion of `markusw` they are valuable.

Answer (score 1):

First, You code won't compile unless You are using some custom implementation of List.
For what I can understand from You question it should be something like

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class DepositoBancario {
    private String banco;
    private List<String> interes;

    DepositoBancario(String s) {
        String[]v = s.split("[ :]"); // split input string by colon or space
        if(v.length != 2) {          // check if there are just two fields
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid syntax, two fields expected: " + s);
        }
        banco = v[0];
        interes = new ArrayList<String>();
        interes.add(v[1]);
    }
}
```